# Matlab - Select cells incrementally down an array

Tags: matlab, sequence

I am an R user, flirting with Matlab.

If I have a data set such as this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

How do I select values 2:4, and skip two cells, and then select 7:9 (...and so on)?

I've tried with the following loop on column 16 in my data, but only select a single number incrementally, rather than the range of values:

```
% Select GVA of regions
nuts3 = 30;
for nuts3 = 1:Nnuts3
regionGVA = datanum(2:4:length(datanum),16);
end
```

Comment: How it can be done in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB you can easily generate indices with the [colon operator](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html). Very useful for creating complex indexing slices is the [end keyword](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html).

Here's how one could do what you want:

```
% Generate some easily recognised data
data = [1;1; zeros(N-2,1)];
for ii = 3:N
    data(ii) = sum(data(ii-2:ii-1)); end

% Index said data at positions 2:4, 7:9, ...

% before R2016b: 
slice = data(bsxfun(@plus, (2:4)', 0:5:end-3))

% after R2016b: 
slice = data((2:4)' + (0:5:end-3))
```

Note that this outputs a matrix. If you want a simple, plain column vector, just do

```
slice = slice(:);
```